# Javascript - use json data inside another ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use some data returned from an ajax request to construct a string, which then needs to be posted back using ajax. However the variable I'm assigning the data to is not in the scope of the second request and thus returning an 'var is undefined' error. In the example below I need to post the data returned from the first request (

```
var cUrl = '/api/courses/a';
var pUrl = '/api/courses/b/pages/1?page_body=';
var bodyData = '';

$.getJSON(cUrl, function(cData){ 
    bodyData = '<div id="' + cData.id + '">' + cData.description + '</div>';
});
('body').on('click', '#add_btn, function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',   
    url: pUrl + bodyData,
    headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"},
    success: function(result) {
    alert('Successfully Added!');
    }
    });
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Many Thanks!

Comment: You have several obvious syntax errors in your code, notably the `body` selector missing the `$` and the missing quote around `#add_btn`.

Comment: I also think one can manage to click the add before the bodyData is populated. Also is this on load? Please show the wrapping script too

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to handle the click event only if you have the json response data, so:

1. Just add the click event handler in the `getJSON` callback.
2. Or trigger a custom event when you get the json response, and create the click event handler for `#add_btn` in the custom event handler. With that the `#add_btn` click event will only fire when you have your json response.